# Is it possible to define a for loop in this way?

Tags: c++

Is there some way to write for loop with "double" init-expression?

```
vector<int> v;
//...vector filling...
for (vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin() AND vector<int>::iterator e = v.end(); i != e; ++i){ ...}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  for (int i=0, j=10; i<10; ++i, ++j) {
    std::cout << i << ", " << j << "\n";
  }
}
```

however, the types of the variables you are initializing must be the same, since you need to use the comma operator.

Comment: Ohh i got it now. The type must be the same. Thank you.

Comment: In this context comma is a punctuator.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, use a comma:

```
vector<int> v;

// ...
for (vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin(), e = v.end(); i != e; ++i)
{

}
```

Why this "works" is due to how a `for`-statement is defined (I've added a semicolon after my implied `for-init-statement` for clarity):

> `for (` *expression-statement* or *simple-declaration* `;` *condition*<sub>opt</sub> `;` *expression*<sub>opt</sub> `)`

A simple declaration is a type followed by a comma separated list of declarators (which is an identifier, maybe pointer/reference/array notation, and an optional initializer).

Comment: Thank you. You do not use `vector<int>::iterator` with `e`. Why?

Comment: Because a declaration starts with a type specifier followed by a comma separated list of declarators. This is the same outside of the sugar in the `for` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Use a comma.

```
for (vector<int> i = v.begin(), e = v.end(); i != e; ++i){ ...}
```

Comment: I edited your post because your intent I think was correct, just the syntax was wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. I just took what the OP originally posted and turned an "AND" into a comma.